# Restore broken magento 2 install

Tags: magento-2.1

my copy of magento 2 is broken and I can't retrieve it. I would like to do a new installation but I would like to keep the data (products, categories, set of attributes). How could i move that data from the old database to the new one?
thanks

Comment: Can you please give more information. What do you see in your var/log reports? What is the error? Do you just have a blank page? What did you do to break it? Do you have a host? If yes , do they take backups?...

Answer (score 0):

Federico.

Here is the Possible solution.

1. When You install your new Magento set your Old database as database option.
2. Change base_url in database with new one in core_config_data table.

But If you had some custom modules in your previous magento then you may be need some more steps(Tuff & custom).

Cheers.

Comment: This won't work if the reason is that he has a wrong configuration (prob it)